# Vaadin combo box filtered drop-down with hyperlink option for drop-down items

Tags: javascript, combobox, vaadin, polymer-1.0, vaadin-grid

I have an interesting requirement. I am showing filtered drop-down using vaadin combo box. I need to display the drop-down items with hyperlink option. Upon clicking that drop-down item I need to navigate to the relevant item.
How to add hyperlink to the vaadin filtered drop-down combo box?

Comment: It sounds like you are using the wrong UI component. I think tou want a navigation menu instead of a dropdown select. Correct me if I’m wrong :)

Comment: If you want to use vaadin-combo-box for this, I would try to use a value-changed listener and trigger the navigation from that.